# Action when text field is filled with a certain character count with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to have a specific action occur (a class removed from a button) when there is a certain number of characters typed into a text input field.  I know how to have an action occur when there is a typing action within the field, but not when it is filled with a certain number of characters or not.

This is what I have:

Jquery:

```
   $("input[id='experience']").keyup(function() {
        $("#fan_choice").find('a').removeClass('faded'); 

           var $buttonlink = $('#fan_choice').find('a');
       $buttonlink.attr('href', $buttonlink.attr('href').replace('#', '/artists'));

    });
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<span id="welcome_two" class="hidden">
<div id="fan_choice">
<a id="submit_two" href="#" class="button faded">Continue &raquo;</a>
<div class="styled_textarea">
        {{ Form::textarea('experience', null, array(
        'id'      => 'experience',
        'onfocus' => 'this.value=\'\'; setbg(\'$f0f7f8\');',
        'onblur'  => 'setbg(\'white\')',
        'rows'    => 10,
        ));}}
</div>
</div>
</span>
```

I am using Laravel 4.  I would like the class "faded" to be removed from the "a" button, and I would like the "href" of the button changed to "/artists" when there is a certain amount of characters typed into the input box.  If the characters are deleted, I would like the class faded to be added back to the button, and the "href" to change back to the default "#".  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the input element can be changed in many ways, don't rely on keyboard events alone. Better, have a timer that checks the input length every second and takes the action, for example:

```
function check() {
    var ok = $("input").val().length > 10;
    $("button").css("opacity", ok ? 1 : 0.5);
}

$(function() {
    setInterval(check, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69YjR/